# How to maintain defaults in a function when using the pipe in R?

Tags: r, magrittr

I feel like this should be a really easy task, but I can't seem to find the answer online. I simply want to do something like this:

`stringr::str_interp("x <- ${rnorm(1)}") %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()`

But that doesn't work; when I call `x` it tells me it cannot be found. I know it's a valid series of functions because this works:

`eval(parse(text = stringr::str_interp("x <- ${rnorm(1)}")))`

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks!

NOTE: I'm using the [github version](https://github.com/hadley/stringr) of `stringr`, which is where the [`str_interp`](https://github.com/hadley/stringr/blob/master/R/interp.R) function comes from.

Comment: It goes from the inside out, so I think it should be `str_interp("x <- ${rnorm(1)}") %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval` since `parse()` goes inside `eval()`.  String it, parse it, evaluate it.

Comment: Sigh... It's clearly been a very long day. You're right, it's supposed to be switched. But that's still not working. I think it's because it also tries to pass the dot to the first argument of `eval`, which is `file = ""`. I want to bypass that initial passing of the dot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here. First, nested functions get evaluated from the inside out, so it should be

```
str_interp --> parse --> eval
```

since `parse()` goes inside `eval()`. String it, parse it, evaluate it. Next, you will need to evaluate it in an environment other than the default environment of `eval()`, which is the parent frame.  I chose the global environment.

```
library(magrittr)
str_interp("x <- ${rnorm(1)}") %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval(globalenv())
x
# [1] 0.1542613
```

**Note:** The necessary functions to reproduce this are in the `stringr` development version, found here: https://github.com/hadley/stringr/blob/master/R/interp.R