# Which environment should be called when using eval( ) in a function?

Tags: r, scope, eval

I've got a set of functions that I'm trying to work with and I'm struggling to figure out why the assignment isn't working. Here are the functions I'm using:

```
new_timeline <- function() {
  timeline = structure(list(), class="timeline")

  timeline$title <- list("text" = list("headline" = NULL, "text" = NULL),
                         "start_date" = list("year" = NULL, "month" = NULL, "day" = NULL),
                         "end_date" = list("year" = NULL, "month" = NULL, "day" = NULL))

  return(timeline)
}

.add_date <- function(self, date, time_type) {
  valid_date <- stringr::str_detect(date, "^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{1,2}){0,2}$")
  if (!valid_date) {
    stringr::str_interp("Your ${time_type} date does not appear to be formatted correctly. It must be of the form 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Only the year is required.") %>% stop()
  }

  date_elements <- date %>% as.character() %>% stringr::str_split(" ") %>% unlist()
  date <- date_elements[1] %>% stringr::str_split("-") %>% unlist()
  stringr::str_interp("self$title$${time_type}_date$year <- date[1]") %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()
  if (!is.na(date[2])) stringr::str_interp("self$title$${time_type}_date$month <- date[2]") %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()
  if (!is.na(date[3])) stringr::str_interp("self$title$${time_type}_date$day <- date[3]") %>% parse(text = .) %>% eval()

  return(self)
}

edit_title <- function(self, headline = NULL, text = NULL, start_date = NULL, end_date = NULL) {

  if (class(self) != "timeline") stop("The object passed must be a timeline object.")
  if (is.null(headline) && is.null(self$title$text$headline)) stop("Headline cannot be empty when adding a new title.")

  if (!is.null(headline)) self$title$text$headline <- headline
  if (!is.null(text)) self$title$text$text <- text
  if (!is.null(start_date)) self <- .add_date(self, date = start_date, time_type = "start")
  if (!is.null(end_date)) self <- .add_date(self, date = end_date, time_type = "end")

  return(self)
}
```

***EDIT: The above code has been severely reduced per a request in the comments. The code is still sufficient to reproduce the error.***

I know that's a bit long-winded, so I apologize. The first function establishes a new timeline object. The third function allows us to change the title of the timeline object and the second function is a helper function that handles dates. The code would be used like this:

```
library(magrittr)
#devtools::install_github("hadley/stringr")
library(stringr)

tl <- new_timeline()
tl <- tl %>% edit_title(headline = "My Timeline", text = "Example", start_date = "2015-10-18")
```

The code runs with no errors, but when I call `tl$title$start_date$year`, it comes back as `NULL`. Using an answer I got in [this previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33161303/how-to-maintain-defaults-in-a-function-when-using-the-pipe-in-r), I tried to set `envir = globalenv()` within the `eval` function. When I do that, the function returns an error saying that object self cannot be found.

So I'm under the impression that `self` is held in the parent.frame(). So I add both of these to a list: `envir = list(globalenv(), parent.frame())`. This causes the function to run without error, but there's still no assignment.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: While running your example, I get `could not find function "edit_timeline"`.

Comment: @Pascal Good call; that's a typo on my part. It's since been corrected.

Comment: oh man, environments get quite convoluted with the pipe operator.  Any chance you can simplify this example?  After a quick read through, most of the code doesnt look relevant.

Comment: @bunk Yeah, let me go through and see what can be removed.

Comment: @bunk You got me thinking about where things were going wrong and I think I found a solution. If I change the assignment operator from `<-` to `<<-`, everything works fine. Any chance you'd be able to explain why it's necessary to use that in this context?

Comment: this is just such a strange way to do this, it's hard to grok what is happening.  I don't really understand why you are using `str_interp` in the first place.  You could do `self$title[[paste0(time_type),"_date"]]$month <- date[2]` for example.  I think a good rule of thumb is to avoid having code in strings.

Comment: the `<<-` is working because it will work its way back through the parent environments until it finds the variable.  If you want to do it this way, I would define `e <- environment()` at the beginning of `.add_date` and pass `envir = e` to `eval()`.  I will take some more experimentation to find out exactly how many parent frames you have to go back from the eval to get the proper variable (basically how many functions it is wrapped in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I think you could probably do away with all of the code parsing and just pass variables in `[[` for your assignments.  Anyway, when you use the pipe operator a bunch of function wrapping happens so determining how many frames to go back is painful.  Here are a couple solutions modifying the `.add_date` function.

You already found one, using `<<-`, since it searches back through the parent environments until it finds the variable (or doesnt and assigns it in the global).

Another would be just storing the function `environment()` and passing that to `eval`.

A third would be counting how many frames deep you go, and using `sys.frame` to tell `eval` which environment to look in.

```
.add_date <- function(self, date, time_type) {
    valid_date <- stringr::str_detect(date, "^[0-9]{4}(-[0-9]{1,2}){0,2}$")
    if (!valid_date) {
        stringr::str_interp("Your ${time_type} date does not appear to be formatted correctly. It must be of the form 'yyyy-mm-dd'. Only the year is required.") %>% stop()
    }

    ## Examining environemnts
    e <- environment()                                                              # current env
    efirst <- sys.nframe()                                                          # frame number
    print(paste("Currently in frame", efirst))
    envs <- stringr::str_interp("${date}") %>% parse(text=.) %>% {.; sys.frames()}  # list of frames
    elast <- stringr::str_interp("${date}") %>% parse(text=.) %>% {.; sys.nframe()} # number of last
    print(paste("Went", elast, "frames deep."))

    ## Go back this many frames in eval
    goback <- efirst-elast

    date_elements <- date %>% as.character() %>% stringr::str_split(" ") %>% unlist()
    date <- date_elements[1] %>% stringr::str_split("-") %>% unlist()

    ## Solution 1: use sys.frame
    stringr::str_interp("self$title$${time_type}_date$year <- date[1]") %>%
      parse(text = .) %>% eval(envir=sys.frame(goback)) 

    ## Solution 2: use environment defined in function
    if (!is.na(date[2])) stringr::str_interp("self$title$${time_type}_date$month <- date[2]") %>%
      parse(text = .) %>% eval(envir=e)

    return(self)
}
```

Comment: Such a simple solution. I don't know why I didn't think to access the list with `[[`... I appreciate the explanation of the environment and frames and demonstrating how I can go about debugging that, but I ended up using your simplification to fix my code. Thanks for the help!

Comment: glad to hear it! that is definetly the way to go